# Как сохранить \n в children React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Вот из этого:

```
<MyComponent>
  Обычная строка
  Ещё одна строка
  Ну и третья строка
</MyComponent>
```

...Обращаясь к `children`, мне бы хотелось получить это:
`"Обычная строка\n Ещё одна строка\n Ну и третья строка"`
А не это `"Обычная строка Ещё одна строка Ну и третья строка"`...

Comment: Возможно ответ дали в этом вопросе https://translated.turbopages.org/proxy_u/en-ru.ru.cda14017-63e7faad-dc95b939-74722d776562/https/stackoverflow.com/questions/36260013/react-display-line-breaks-from-saved-textarea

Comment: @ksa, там идет ввод в textarena пользователем, а мне нужно вводить в сам тег разработчиком. Мне нужно как-то передавать символ `\n` и желательно без `{\` \`}`: такую логику реализует тег *pre*, но почему-то он у меня не работает, как следует.

Comment: Так ты пробовал использовать теги `<br />` или нет?

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы без них работало